# Parse a line to get specific string in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new for python and tried to get parse the URL from the line. How can I get the line?

```
application_url: https://hafaf.daff.io
```

I tried to use split but I could not get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So split works as such:

```
mystring = "Hello, my name is Sam!"
print(mystring.split('Hello')[1])
```

That will output:
", my name is Sam!"

What split does it quite literally as it sounds like, is split on a specific string or character.

So to get the url there you'd do the following:

```
my_url = "application_url: https://hafaf.daff.io".split("application_url: ")[1]
```

Which would result in the variable my_url being  "https://hafaf.daff.io"

Do note the inclusion of the spaces when splitting.

Split breaks a string into a LIST object which you can then access by index. So when I go to get your url from that string I search for the second index being 1 as the "application_url: " is in position 0.